# Confused about Classes, Instances and Methods in ColdFusion

Tags: oop, coldfusion

My question is probably best illustrated with an example. In javascript I'm used to being able to do stuff like this:

```
// create a simple class
function myClass() {
  this.attr_example = "attribute";
}
myClass.prototype.do_something = function() {
  return "did something";
}

// create an instance of it, and modify as needed
var thing = new myClass();
thing.myMethod = function(arg) {
  return "myMethod stuff";
}

// ... so that this works as expected
console.log(thing.myMethod());
console.log(thing.do_something());
console.log(thing.attr_example);
```

When it comes to doing something similar in ColdFusion, I get stuck. I constantly find myself wanting to do things like this:

```
<cfscript>
  // thing.cfc contains a normal cfcomponent definition with some methods
  var thing = createObject("component","Thing");
  function formattedcost() {
    return "#LSCurrencyFormat(this.cost)#";
  }
  thing.formattedcost = formattedcost;
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
  #thing.formattedcost()#
</cfoutput>
```

Let's assume that for this question, it doesn't make sense to add "formattedcost" as a method on the Thing class because it is purely presentational. Let's also assume that simply using `#LSCurrencyFormat(thing.cost)#` in the `<cfoutput>` tags wont suffice either because we need the instance of `Thing` to be evaluated by a templating system (mustache in this case). Even further, I'd like to avoid having to create another .cfc file just to extend my `Thing` class to add a couple of methods.

**What can I do? Is this style of programming possible in ColdFusion?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do this:

## Thing.cfc

```
<cfcomponent output="false" accessors="true">
    <cfproperty name="cost" type="numeric">
    <cffunction name="init" output="false" access="public" 
        returntype="any" hint="Constructor">
        <cfargument name="cost" type="numeric" required="true"/>
        <cfset variables.instance = structNew()/>
        <cfset setCost(arguments.cost)>
        <cfreturn this/>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

## test.cfm

```
<cfscript>
  // thing.cfc contains a normal cfcomponent definition with some methods
  thing = new Thing(725);
  function formattedcost() {
    return "#LSCurrencyFormat(getCost())#";
  }
  thing.formattedcost = formattedcost;
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
  #thing.formattedcost()#
</cfoutput>
```

## Result

```
$725.00
```

Comment: thank you! i guess i was almost there! this does raise a further question, though: what does `<cfset variables.instance = structNew()/>` do?

Comment: Sorry that's boiler code I use when I write my CFCs. You don't need it.

Comment: Hey @DustMason, @orangepips set statement creates an internal instance variable, so that you can store persistent data inside the CFC without letting it leak out of the object. It's a great thing to use for variables that need to be available for all methods in an object that you don't want external applications to get their hands on.

Comment: @Dan Short: yes that would be the extended answer.

Comment: I see, so nodes on the variables.instance struct would work just like "@" variables do in Ruby (as an example)? Thanks for clarifying.